# Use layout instead of parts php mvc

Tags: php, templates

I trying to write my own MVC (Please don't suggest me any existing mvc I want to make my own) and now to render a page I do this:

Header:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<!-- Some contents -->
</head>
<body>
```

Footer:

```
</body>
</html>
```

Index function of a controller:

```
public function index(){
    $this->view->render('header');
    $this->view->render('index');
    $this->view->render('footer');
}
```

Render function:

```
public function render($file){
    require "views/$file.php";
}
```

Instead of doing that how I can do something like this?

Layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<!-- Some contents -->
</head>
<body>
<?= $page //$page will be replaced with index.php content ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Index function of a controller:

```
public function index(){
    $this->view->render('layout', 'index');
}
```

Comment: You can write your own MVC thing [that's actually very good for learning purposes, at least it was for me], but consider using an existing templating language. You can start with [PHP_TI](http://arshaw.com/phpti/) for instance, and then you'll find out that Twig is just anything you need.

Comment: Something like ... `ob_start(); require '../file.php'; $page = ob_get_contents();` ? Look into output buffering.. bare in mind you will need to make `$page` global to access it in your layout (or maybe I should say 'in the same scope').

Comment: @FDL Yes this will solve my problem, thank you :)

Comment: You could start by understanding the difference between view and [a simple template](http://codeangel.org/articles/simple-php-template-engine.html). Also, please never use `global` variables (or any other global state for that matter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a render function like:

```
function render ($template, array $environment = array()) {
    extract($environment);
    ob_start();
    include $template;
    $contents = ob_get_clean();
    return $content;
}
```

The `extract()` function will import all variables from the array into the current scope making them available to your template.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

`ob_start()` will buffer all content from that point onwards.
`ob_get_clean()` will get the contents of the buffer end ends the buffering of output.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php